# Clothes washer , fridge, electric dryer , electric range not working

Tags: electrical

First time post here, hoping someone can figure out what is wrong with my electric circuit .
Our Clothes washer , fridge,electric dryer , electric range sometimes will not work(no power) but will suddenly back on again . Clothes washer ,fridge sharing the same circuit with 20A circuit breaker, range and dryer are individual 240v 30A and 50A . 
can anyone tell me what is wrong ? Or anything to look for ? Thanks

Comment: How long is the outage (usually)?  Do all 3 circuits go off and on simultaneously?

Comment: Outage sometimes couple seconds sometimes couple hours. Funny thing is when I turn the knob on the range power will be come back on most of the time on all three circuits.

Comment: Yea, you have a big problem. Call an electrician ASAP. It sounds like one of your hot legs has a bad connection. This is serious as high resistance connections are a fire hazard.

Comment: Your fridge and clothes washer also need their own dedicated 20A circuits.

Comment: Ditto. BIG problem. Get it investigated today if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

You apparently have a serious intermittent power circuit. It could be...

1. A fault in the utility drop to your property
2. A problem with the meter or meter socket wiring
3. Faulty connection between the meter and the mains breaker in your power panel
4. Bad mains breaker in your panel
5. Loose connection between mains breaker and the bus bars in your panel

There obviously could also be other problems but I focused on likely issues that would be affecting multiple circuits to appliances in your abode.

Intermittent circuits are very dangerous and can lead to arcing and heat build up in the faulty connection that could result in a fire. In your situation it is strongly recommended that you contact a professional electrician as soon as possible to come out and inspect your electrical installation and hopefully correct the problems before any serious injury or damage occurs.